# How to save an email to disk without making Outlook unresponsive/look busy?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, save

I wrote a small Outlook-PlugIn (VSTO/C#) which stores specific emails in a user-specified directory. My problem is that sometimes there are emails with big attachments and/or many (50+) emails to be saved at once.

The PlugIn handles all that but in some cases Outlook get's unresponsive and has a progressbar showing up. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? (for example another way of saving those emails)

If not, maybe someone has an idea on how to 'work around' this behavior (for example stop the saving when Outlook is 'used' by the user)

*edit this takes place in .NET 4 and must be compatible to Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

Comment: are you currently saving the emails to disk asynchronously?

Comment: no, I don't. I just call SaveAs(filepath);. I didn't even know that was possible. I don't seem to be able to find anything about an async save method, could you tell me a little more?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a delegate that will run the method asynchronously.
This would mean that the (possibly) long running `SaveAs(filepath)` will not block the UI and cause Outlook to show the progress bar/become unresponsive to user input.

A really good simple example of this style of asynchronous coding can be found here [Using AsyncCallBack](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0420__Thread/UseAsyncCallback.htm)

And here is the official [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx)

Comment: oh, you meant running the SaveAs method itself as an async statement. I don't think that will solve my problem. The SaveAs method is already called in a Thread, the problem is/seems to be that the UI of Outlook is somehow 'used' by something inside the SaveAs method. Anyway, I'll try it, even if it doesn't solve this problem, it has some benefits.

Comment: yeh, that's the best i could come up with. Googled around a bit and can't seem to find any exposed C# awaitable methods or anything. Let me know how you get on!